# PyTorch Dataloader for multiple files with sliding window

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I am working on a problem where I have multiple CSVs files and I need to read those multiple CSVs one by one with a sliding window. Let’s assume that, one CSV file is having 330 data points and the window size is 32 so we should be having (10*32 = 320) and the last 10 points will be discarded.

I started making a dataset that looks like this but after spending too much time, I am not able to get it working. The current code looks like this,

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, data_folder, window_size):
    self.data_folder = data_folder
    self.data_file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(data_folder)]
    print(self.data_file_list)
    self.window_size = window_size
    
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.data_file_list[0])

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    filename = self.data_file_list[idx]
    data, label = read_file(filename)
    return data, label

def read_file(self, filename):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    data = data.drop(["file_name", "class_name"], axis = 1)
    features = data.drop(["class_no"], axis = 1)
    labels = data["class_no"]
    x = [features[index:index+self.window_size].values for index in range(0, len(features))]
    y = [labels[index:index+self.window_size].values for index in range(0, len(labels))]
    
    return x, y
```

Note: I can’t merge all these CSV files into one.

I am getting this error, `TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()`

Comment: The problem will be the two second last lines. The length of a DataFrame should be determined by `features.shape[0]` or `len(len(features.index))`. The same should hold for the labels DataFrame. This is in my opinion, what also the Error says.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following workaround. According to this, the **getitem** function retrieves a specific window which belongs to a csv file and not the file itself. Towards this direction, find_num_of_windows computes the number of windows occur for a given csv file. The **len**(self) function will return the sum of the windows of all files. In this way, the idx input of the **getitem** function will no longer have an upper limit equal to the number of files. Instead the upper limit would be the number of windows of all files. The create_dataset_dict function assigns to all potential idx values the corresponding filename and window index.

Comments:

- The code needs optimization. Though, I chose a simple way for easier
  understanding.
- I don't know how exatly the read_file function works,
  so I just tried something as an example.

Hope it helps!

```
import csv

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, data_folder, data_list_filename, window_size):
    self.data_folder = data_folder
    self.data_file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(data_folder)]
    self.window_size = window_size
    self.total_windows, self.dataset_dict = create_dataset_dict()


def find_num_of_windows(self, path_to_file):
    rows = 0
    with open(path_to_file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        line_count = 0
        rows = sum([1 for row in csv_reader])
    windows = rows // self.window_size


def create_dataset_dict(self):
    total_windows = 0
    idx = 0
    dataset_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(self.data_file_list)):
        windows_of_current_file = find_num_of_windows(self.data_file_list[i])
        total_windows += windows_of_current_file

        for j in range(idx:idx + windows_of_current_file):
            dataset_dict[idx] = {
                "filename": self.data_file_list[i],
                "window_index": j
            }

    return total_windows, dataset_dict


def read_file(filename, w_index):
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        line_idx = 0
        data = []
        labels = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_idx >= w_index and line_idx < w_index + self.window_size:
                data.append(row[0])
                labels.append(row[1])
                
        return data, labels
        
    
def __len__(self):
    return self.total_windows
    

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    
    filename = self.dataset_dict[idx]["filename"]
    w_index = self.dataset_dict[idx]["window_index"]
    data, label = read_file(filename, w_index)
    return data, label
```

Example:

Assuming we have 3 CSV files - csv_1, csv_2 and csv_3

From csv_1 we can extract 2 windows, from csv_2 we can extract 3 windows and from csv_3 we can extract 1 window.

Then:

1. find_num_of_windows(path_to_csv_1) returns 2
2. find_num_of_windows(path_to_csv_2) returns 3
3. find_num_of_windows(path_to_csv_3) returns 1

By calling create_dataset_dict() function, the dataset dictionary is created and looks like the one below:

```
{ 
  1: {
       "filename": path_to_csv_1,
       "window_index": 1
     },
  2: {
       "filename": path_to_csv_1,
       "window_index": 2
     },
  3: {
       "filename": path_to_csv_2,
       "window_index": 1
     },
  4: {
       "filename": path_to_csv_2,
       "window_index": 2
     },
  5: {
       "filename": path_to_csv_2,
       "window_index": 3
     },
  6: {
       "filename": path_to_csv_3,
       "window_index": 1
     }
}
```

If we now call the **getitem** function using an idx in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], we can retrieve the corresponding window using the aformentioned dictionary. For example, if we give 4 as input to **getitem** we will retrieve the second window of file csv_2.

Comment: Thanks @yannis, I changed the code and now I am having this error `RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [77516, 32, 17] at entry 0 and [64979, 32, 17] at entry 1` as I have multiple files and each file can be [TotalWindowSize, OneWindowSize, Features] where OneWindowSize, Features will be same all the files but first TotalWindowSize will be different.

Comment: Hi @Pythonic! If you followed the exact logic of my solution,  you shouldn't face such an issue. Let's assume you have 3 CSV files. From csv_1 we can extract 2 windows, from csv_2 - 3 windows and  from csv_3 just 1 window. In total, we have 6 windows. Thus __len__(self) function will return 6. The idx of getitem should take values in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] that corresponds to windows ids, and not in [1, 2, 3] that would correspond to CSV ids. Probably, if you give CSV id to getitem you will end up with different batch sizes. That's why I use create_dataset_dict in order to fetch windows directly.

Comment: I have just updated my answer by providing an explanation of how the code works